# C# LINQ query fails when using IsAbstract property during derived class scan with reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I am using reflection to scan for all the class types that derive (are assignable) from a particular base class.  That part works fine.  But when I try to filter the resulting list by the IsAbstract property to get a list of only the non-abstract classes, the LINQ query that does the filtering fails to work correctly.  Instead, I had to resort to a *foreach* loop and do it "manually."  I tried this query first:

```
       if (!bAcceptAbstract)
           retListFiltered = (from typeClass in retList where typeClass.GetType().IsAbstract == false select typeClass).ToList();
```

But that didn't filter out the class types marked as abstract.

I then tried:

```
retListFiltered = (from typeClass in retList where !typeClass.GetType().IsAbstract select typeClass).ToList();
```

But again, no filtering.  Why doesn't the LINQ query seem to respect the value of the IsAbstract propery?

Below is the code I ended up having to use:

```
   public static List<System.Type> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly primaryAssembly, bool bAcceptAbstract = true) where T : class
    {
        if (primaryAssembly == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The primary assembly is unassigned.");

        List<System.Type> retList =
            primaryAssembly.GetTypes().Where(type =>
                typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .ToList();

        List<System.Type> retListFiltered = new List<System.Type>();


        foreach (System.Type typeClass in retList)
        {
            if (bAcceptAbstract || !typeClass.IsAbstract)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("INCLUDED {0} class, abstract value: {1}.", typeClass.Name, typeClass.IsAbstract.ToString()));

                retListFiltered.Add(typeClass);
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("IGNORED abstract class: {0}.", typeClass.Name));
        }
        return retListFiltered;
    }
```

Comment: why are you calling GetType on typeClass? `typeClass.GetType().IsAbstract` should be `typeClass.IsAbstract`, so:
`(from typeClass in retList where typeClass.IsAbstract == false select typeClass).ToList();`

Comment: The other comments are right. The sequence `obj.GetType().IsAbstract` wil always return false because `GetType()` always finds the concrete (non-abstract) actual type at runtime, and by nature, that is not abstract. **Addition:** If `obj` is already an object that represents a type, i.e. if `obj` is declared as a `System.Type` variable, then `obj.GetType()` will return a concrete derived class of `System.Type` which is the `internal` class `System.RuntimeType`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Well, `typeof(System.Type).IsAbstract` is true, but clearly `typeClass.GetType()` will return the actual concrete subclass of `System.Type` which is used. It happens to be an `internal` (non-abstract of course) class `System.RuntimeType` (as I just said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example

```
if (!bAcceptAbstract)
       retListFiltered = (from typeClass in retList where typeClass.GetType().IsAbstract == false select typeClass).ToList();
```

the typeClass is already a Type, so there's no need to call GetType() on it again. The following works:

```
(from typeClass in retList where typeClass.IsAbstract == false select typeClass).ToList();
```

You can write

```
public static List<System.Type> GetAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly primaryAssembly, bool bAcceptAbstract = true) where T : class
{
    if (primaryAssembly == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("The primary assembly is unassigned.");

    return !bAcceptAbstract ? primaryAssembly.GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsAbstract).ToList() : primaryAssembly.GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks and thank you to all those that pointed that out in their comments.